# Array List Insert Method

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, insert

I am trying to insert an element in an array. My method is supposed to increase the the size of the array by one and insert the element in the proper spot. The issue: It adds the element in the proper spot and extends the array, but it gets rid of the original element in the spot and inserts a null.
My code:

```
 public void insert(int point, Person person){
    Person [] newList = new Person[this.size()+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < point; i++){
      newList[i] = list[i];
    }
    newList[point] = person;

    for(int i = point+1; i<this.size(); i++){
      newList[i] = list[i];

    }
   this.list = new Person[this.size()+1];
    for(int i = 0; i <this.size(); i++){
      list[i] = newList[i];
    }
  }
```

The array output:

```
> FBArrayList name = new FBArrayList()
 [DrJava Input Box]
> name.list[0] = new Person("Emma", 7)
Person@20a3d02a
> name.list[1] = new Person("Daniel", 8)
Person@6e8a93de
> name.list[2] = new Person("Bradley", 9)
Person@327556d1
> name.list[3] = new Person("Monica", 1)
Person@3d886c83
> name.list[4] = new Person("Connor", 2)
Person@76b41f9c
> name.list[5] = new Person("Fedor", 3)
Person@462a5d25
> name.insert(3, new Person("David", 4))
> for(int i = 0; i<7; i++){
System.out.println(name.list[i].getName());
}
Emma
Daniel
Bradley
David
Connor
Fedor
java.lang.NullPointerException
> name.list
{ Person@20a3d02a, Person@6e8a93de, Person@327556d1, Person@1d1a8b9, Person@76b41f9c, Person@462a5d25, null }
```

Any suggestions about why I am losing Monica or how I might go about fixing it.

Comment: Random thought - instead of recreating `list` at the end and copying over the contents of `newList`, why not just do `list = newList`?

Comment: That is a good question. I am not sure why I'm not doing it that way. Thanks @Chris

Answer (score 4):

```
public void insert(int point, Person person){
  Person [] newList = new Person[this.size()+1];
  for(int i = 0; i < point; i++){
    newList[i] = list[i];
  }
  newList[point] = person;

  // this part copies the remainder of the original list to the new list after
  // your inserted entry
  for(int i = point; i < this.size(); i++){
    newList[i+1] = list[i];

  }

  this.list = newList;
}
```

Comment: Thx for adding the clarification on where the fix is exactly and why it fixes it :)

Answer (score -1):

You did a:

```
name.insert(3, new Person("David", 4))
```

which inserted "David" in position 3 and overwrote "Monica"!

Comment: But it's supposed to insert, not replace...how should it be fixed?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly: am I overwriting Monica before I move it in to the next array?

Comment: Hi @Chris. Thanks for commenting, you bring up a good point. Can the author give us more information on what the `FBArrayList()` is and how the `insert` method works. Maybe this is just a standard Java `ArrayList`; is that correct?

Comment: Hi @user3242955. That's what it looks like when you do the `name.insert(3...`. But I'm not sure how the `FBArrayList()` is implemented...

Comment: `FBArrayList` is the class OP is implementing, with the `insert` method as written in the question

Comment: Hi @user3242955. Jason's answer is the one you should use!

Comment: Who down voted my answer? It shouldn't be a down vote, since the `insert` was the reason that "Monica" was not showing up in the printed output!